# Disk performance very slow on esxi 6

Tags: performance, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have dedicated server with esxi6.

I uploaded many iso from vsphere window client and i have  5 vms on it with 2 X1 TB HD SATA.

The upload was quick but just now it is taking forever to upload.

These are the results from esx logs . i am sure what are good results so i am posting here

One warning is this

```
Device t10.ATA_____TOSHIBA_DT01ACA100____
_____________________________237DXREPS 
performance has deteriorated. I/O latency 
increased from average value of 10650 
microseconds to 324540 microseconds.
warning
2/19/2017 9:12:49 PM
```

I saw the disk performace and it show this

[Disk performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwjIF.png)

Comment: Chexk your VM IO performance as one of your VM might be pushing those IO especially during heavy IO operation